# program looks for libstdc++.so.6 in wrong place and seems to ignore LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following error when running my program:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by ...
```

I know that `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` is the wrong version, so I add the path to the correct version to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/gcc-4.8.3/lib
```

The command:

```
strings /usr/local/gcc-4.8.3/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

gives me:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

However, the error persists, as if the program doesn't see the new version I added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Any advice about what could be happening?

Comment: Can you post the output of ldd ?

Comment: thank you, this helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is caused by linking against the wrong listdc++ lib as you've already identified. You are exporting only libstdc++ at 32bit and not the one at 64bit.

Try adding the `libstdc++` contained in `lib64`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/gcc-4.8.3/lib:/usr/local/gcc-4.8.3/lib64
```

Make sure the `LD_LBRARY_PATH` is correctly set **before** your code is compiled. To check if the binary has been linked against the correct `libstdc++` you can use `ldd`. The correct output should contain the following line:

```
/lib/usr/local/gcc-4.8.3/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: thank you, adding /usr/local/gcc-4.8.3/lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH solved my problem